# Displaying Static References on a Class Diagrams - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, uml, class-diagram

I've been looking for a way to do this for a while and I couldn't find any answers. Here is quick explanation of my situation:

In my solution there are some "manager classes" that have a static reference to itself. For instance:

```
public static UIManager Instance;
Instance = this;
```

All those manager classes execute at the very start of the application. So at any given point any class can call:

```
UIManager.Instance.DoSomething();
```

Everything was great, until now that I have to create a class diagram.

Visual studio class diagram feature makes it possible to trace references with the 'Show Assossiation' option. For instance for the same UIManager I get:[image]

That's because the UIManager class has a reference to the PauseMenu Class.

However the 'AreaChecker' class which communicates with the UIManager through the static Instance variable, doesn't have any link displayed in the class diagram.

[image]

That link is important because, for this example, AreaChecker only works properly if the UIManger class is on the project.

**I want to be able to create that link automatically. Is this supported in any way by the class diagram? If so how can I do it? If not is there another plugin/program that I should download to be able to do that?**

Comment: Why should `AreaChecker` have a link? Where to? And without knowing the code, how should we guess?? Btw: your instance names should start with lower case to distinguish them from types.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Thomas. I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear. 

I want a link  because `AreaChecker` calls a method from the `UIManager`  through the static reference `Instance`.  

Like this: `UIManager.Instance.Method()`. If there was no `UIManger` the `AreaCheker` wouldn't work properly. 

So that's why I wanted this link, so I could see what is really connected. 

For the names, I was using lower case for private variables and uppercase for public ones. Since `Instance` was static and public I named it uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

UML does not have a concept of static variables. So there can't be an association referencing it. You might manually add such an association and stereotype it in some way (e.g. `<<static>>`). This is some kind of work around which you need to describe in the modeling rules of your domain.

Comment: Interesting... I'm not familiar with the standards to that degree, but intuitively it seems a dashed arrow (dependency) would apply.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator A dependency is just the weakest link. You can use that as well. It's just how affirmative the link is meant.